# Are music and or sound effects haram?

Tags: music, halal-haram

May peace be upon you. I am a videographer and I would like to know: is the use of music / sound effects for the intention of setting a mood or scene in a film forbidden? I would like to use certain sound effects that involve the use of instruments in my videos.

Answer (score 1):

[Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/37/159)

> The bell is the musical instrument of the Satan.

[Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/13/4)

> Abu Bakr came to my house while two small Ansari girls were singing
>   beside me the stories of the Ansar concerning the Day of Buath. And
>   they were not singers. Abu Bakr said protestingly, "Musical
>   instruments of Satan in the house of Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) !" It
>   happened on the Id day and Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said, "O Abu Bakr!
>   There is an Id for every nation and this is our Id."

[Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/74/16)

> Narrated Abu 'Amir or Abu Malik Al-Ash'ari: that he heard the Prophet
>   (ﷺ) saying, "From among my followers there will be some people who
>   will consider illegal sexual intercourse, the wearing of silk, the
>   drinking of alcoholic drinks and the use of musical instruments, as
>   lawful. And there will be some people who will stay near the side of a
>   mountain and in the evening their shepherd will come to them with
>   their sheep and ask them for something, but they will say to him,
>   'Return to us tomorrow.' Allah will destroy them during the night and
>   will let the mountain fall on them, and He will transform the rest of
>   them into monkeys and pigs and they will remain so till the Day of
>   Resurrection."

[Some other hadith searched by music](https://sunnah.com/search/?q=music)

From all these hadiths it seems it is allowed in some rare cases with some selected instuments like DUFF but not good/liked action.

As a business: I also worked for a website, they were creating cartoon video (kideo.com) so ask the same question and got the answer like this for educated Ulemas:

- Try to find a new Halal Job
- Keep continue until you get a new job
- Do astaghfar and promise not to accept such job in future for better salary

Answer (score 0):

I work for an Islamic website and we have just started creating videos and came to this question ourselves.

We use nasheeds, preferably without lyrics, and also nature sounds.

We should ask ourselves, why did Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) ask us to recite Quran melodically? Also, we know from the authentic traditions that the Prophet (peace and blessings be upon him) not only allowed music in the weddings but also listened to girls singing.

While listening to girls singing on such an occasion, he interrupted them only once when they sang the following verse, “In our midst is a Prophet who knows what will happen tomorrow”; whence, the Prophet (peace be upon him) told them, “Cut this sentence out, and continue singing what you have been singing earlier.” (Ahmad and Ibn Sa`d)

Comment: The hadith appears also in sahih al-Bukahri [here](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/67/82) and [here](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/64/52) in [Sunan ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/urn/1262160), [Sunan abi Dawod](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/43/150) and [Jami' at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/11/11), but I can't see any relevance to the topic of this question.